# COUNT(*) of GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, group-by

I have a query which returns 644 rows, grouped by several columns. I need to get a count of these rows, 644.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ho.ID,ho.honame,ho.ho_status,SUM(Properties.Value) as [sales value], COUNT(Properties.record_id) as [property count]
FROM HeadOffice ho INNER JOIN Properties ON Properties.head_office_code = ho.id
WHERE Somecondition
GROUP BY ho.ID,ho.honame,ho_status ORDER BY ho_status
```

Despite trying `COUNT(*)`, wrapping it in another query and removing the `GROUP BY`, I can't get '644' back. The closest I've come is 644 rows, all containing '1'. Is this possible?

Comment: What does `select count(1) from (select distinct ID, honame, ho_status from HeadOffice) ignore` return?

Comment: If your original query returns the correct number of rows, why would you alter it when wrapping in Select count(*) from (<Your Original Query>)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way to do it is thusly:

```
SELECT count(1) as NumRows from
(SELECT DISTINCT ho.ID,ho.honame,ho.ho_status,SUM(Properties.Value) as [sales value], COUNT(Properties.record_id) as [property count]
FROM HeadOffice ho INNER JOIN Properties ON clients.head_office_code = ho.id
WHERE Somecondition
GROUP BY ho.ID,ho.honame,ho_status ORDER BY ho_status) x
```

If you want the count plus your columns, use `over`:

```
SELECT 
    count(1) over () as NumRows,
    x.ID,
    x.ho_status,
    x.[sales value],
    x.[property count]
from
(SELECT DISTINCT ho.ID,ho.honame,ho.ho_status,SUM(Properties.Value) as [sales value], COUNT(Properties.record_id) as [property count]
FROM HeadOffice ho INNER JOIN Properties ON clients.head_office_code = ho.id
WHERE Somecondition
GROUP BY ho.ID,ho.honame,ho_status ORDER BY ho_status) x
```

Comment: I was doing COUNT(*) from the above, but this works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will get 1 more row to your list which contains null values for everything but property count and properties value.  That record will have a count and the sum of all property values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ho.ID,ho.honame,ho.ho_status, 
SUM(Properties.Value) as [sales value], 
COUNT(Properties.record_id) as [property count]
FROM HeadOffice ho 
INNER JOIN Properties 
  ON clients.head_office_code = ho.id
WHERE Somecondition
GROUP BY Grouping sets((ho.ID,ho.honame,ho_status),()) 
ORDER BY ho_status
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ho.ID,ho.honame,ho.ho_status,
       SUM(Properties.Value) as [sales value], 
       COUNT(Properties.record_id) as [property count]
FROM HeadOffice ho 
     INNER JOIN Properties ON clients.head_office_code = ho.id
WHERE Somecondition
GROUP BY ho.ID, ho.honame, ho_status ) t
```